# Discord Bot Server Muting

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I'm trying to code a discord bot that server mutes people when i do ".mute @person"

What's wrong with my code?

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
   let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]))
   if(msg.content === ".mute"){
       person.setDeaf
   }
})
```

It says "message not defined"

Comment: are you defined message in some part of your code?? because in the function message is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bot.on('message', msg => {...}` waits for the event `message` then passes that information as the variable `msg` for the function provided.
Inside your function, you refer to `message.guild.member` but `message` is undefined (you passed your event information as `msg`, not `message`). Change your function parameter to message, so it looks like this:
`bot.on('message', message => {...}`)

That would fix the error you're getting, but I'm not sure that function will actually server mute a user. I think what you want [is](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=edit):

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(".mute")) {
        let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
        await person.edit({mute: true});
    }
});
```

Notice I use `message` as the parameter for the function, but I put `async` in front of it because I'm going to be using an asynchronous function. `.edit()` takes a dictionary of data, see the [linked documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/GuildMemberEditData). It is awaited because it is done asynchronously: you call it, then you wait for a response from the server before continuing (to make sure everything happened as expected).

Tested myself, works like a charm.

Comment: I don't know, you gotta figure that out yourself or make a new question. But by reading the docs https://discord.js.org/#/docs , I'm able to see that message.mentions.members is a collection. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members perhaps you can figure out how to loop over each mentioned member.

Comment: @Detry If this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/362830) by clicking the check mark. That way, this question is marked as solved. It also gives you and the answerer some reputation!